# How does time look relatively in a gravity well?

Tags: general-relativity

Relativistically, when two frames, say A & B are moving apart inertially, then the clock of  B will look slow compared to that of A; and the same holds for the clock of A from B.

What does the comparable set up look like in a gravity well, with A at the bottom and B at the top?

My *guess* would be not, because the situation isn't symmetrical; whereas the SR setup is.

I'm not interested in a quantitative calculation; but simply whether they're slower or faster; and simply a confirmation or refutation of the guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

Comment: I'm marking this question for close as 'Too Broad' --- as it is more appropriate for, and well answered as, a google or wikipedia search.

Comment: @dilthiummatrix: I've just scanned the Wikipedia entry that you suggested and it's not answered there - it simply states that there is a dilation effect, as there is in the SR setup - but that situation is symmetrical; I'm asking whether the same setup in a gravity well is symmetrical or not; my guess would be that it's not - because the situation is not; and I'm just looking for a confirmation or refutation of that guess.

Comment: The asnwer is that the situation is indeed asymmetric, cf. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154061/50583)

Comment: I've added this detail to the question.

Comment: @acuriousmind: Thanks, for pointing the duplicate out; it does indeed answer my question in the terms asked for.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but just a mathematical reformulation, if I get you correctly.

So you're in a 2D world with coordinates $(t,r)$ and a metric such as

$g=\mathrm{diag}(-\kappa(r),\dfrac{1}{\kappa(r)}),$

e.g. $\kappa(r)=1-\frac{R}{r}$ for the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric).

You want to solve the [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Affine_geodesics) for the 2-trajectory $x(s)=(t(s),r(s))$ starting at an event $x=(0,r)$ and velocity $w=(w_0,w_1)$ with $g(w,w)=-1$. The solution is some $s$-parametrized line in spacetime that curves towards one direction, eventually ending up at $r=R$. And you want to know how the lightlight grid looks in this world. Here's a link to a talk on the [Schwarzschild case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics).

You consider two guys at $x_A=(0,r_A)$ and $x_B=(0,r_B)$ with $r_B\gg r_A\gg R$ and velocities $v=(1,0)$ (the closer one is at rest, just free falling) and the other guy has some impulse away from $R$, say. These initial conditions give two curves who bend towards $r=R$. Each event in spacetime of course has two outgoing lightlike deformed cones. You're interested in how an the arc-lenght of one guys (say you choose a point and look at a distance of 1 along that guys trajectory) gets "projected" via the light-grid onto the other.

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) (on Gravitational time dilation) might also be relevant. 
And I now see [this SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96478/time-dilation-in-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-metric).

[image]